# ng-show not working with Firebase auth response

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase with the web platform and I'm trying to authenticate a new user clicking on a button and show and a bootstrap alert  (with `ng-show`) whenever the action succeeded or not.

Somehow the alert doesn't show up on the first click and it shown in the second click on the button.

I don't know if it has to do with the problem but Firebase making an http POST request whenever the action succeeded or not, maybe this action prevent from the ng-show to be shown. By the way I tried POST request with `$http` to some url and it does show the alert, so it has to do with Firebase probably.

For example this is the POST request when the action succeeded: 
`XHR finished loading: POST 
"https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=AIzaSyDq8jT_hORoFwefcApBXgiOAYQufpOvI9A".`

It's very weird problem and I don't know what can I do to fix it.
I thought that it's could be a bug on Angular and I tried to switch version of angular from 1.3 to 1.6 and nothing has changed.

here are some parts from my code if this can help somehow:

```
myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.register = function(){

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('john@example.com','123321').then( (user) => {

        console.log(user);
        $scope.alertShow = true;  // not shown on first click
        $scope.errorMessage = user.email;
        console.log($scope.errorMessage);

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        $scope.alertShow = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log($scope.errorMessage);
    })

}

}]);
```

The HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="register()">Register</button>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="alertShow">
        {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. As ng-if dynamically add and remove dom elements, it will trigeer digest cycle.

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="register()">Register</button>

        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-if="alertShow">
            {{ errorMessage }}
        </div>
```

If even ng-if not works, try `$apply` to trigger `$digest` cycle.

```
myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope','$timeout' function($scope,$timeout){

$scope.register = function(){
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('john@example.com','123321').then( (user) => {

        console.log(user);
        $scope.alertShow = true;  // not shown on first click
        $timeout(function (){$scope.$apply()},0);
        $scope.errorMessage = user.email;
        console.log($scope.errorMessage);

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        $scope.alertShow = true;
         $timeout(function (){$scope.$apply()},0);
        $scope.errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log($scope.errorMessage);
    })

}

}]);
```

Comment: it didn't work with ng-if, but it works with $apply. Thank you!